# STEP III 1990: Roots in a trigonometric

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I was doing a question in a STEP maths paper given by

> By considering the graphs of $y=kx$ and $y=\sin x$, show that the equation $kx=\sin x$, where $k>0$, may of $0,1,2$ or $3$ roots in the interval $(4n+1)\dfrac\pi2<x<(4n+5)\dfrac\pi2$, where $n$ is a positive integer.
>
> For a certain given value of $n$, the equation has exactly one root in this interval.  Show that $k$ lies in an interval which may be written as $\sin\delta<k<\dfrac2{(4n+1)\pi}$, where $0<\delta<\dfrac\pi2$ and $$\cos\delta=\left((4n+5)\frac\pi2-\delta\right)\sin\delta.$$
>
> Show that, if $n$ is large, then $\delta\approx\dfrac2{(4n+5)\pi}$ and obtain a second, improved, approximation.

but I got stuck on the $cos(\delta)$ bit. I originally thought that  it would have something to do with the gradient as in most cases the gardient is $\frac{dy}{dx}=tan(\theta)=\frac{sin(\theta)}{cos(\theta)}$ which could be rearanged to get $cos{\theta}$ as the subject but I did this with no success. If anybody could suggest an intuitive way of approaching this I would be really thankful.

Comment: Please do not tag these sorts of problems as algebraic-geometry. From the tag description: "this tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry."

Comment: What have you tried? You've posted all of these questions without showing your work or your understanding. The gradient is a great way to start. What's the condition that you should be looking at?

Comment: @CalvinLin hi thanks for the response. As I started writing out my work on LaTeX I realised that I had a mistake in my previous interpretation of $\delta$. I followed the suggestion for the gradient and I used the calculus version alongside the elementary algebra one ($\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\text{change in y}}{\text{change in x}}$) alongside the fact that the tangent line goes through the origen to arrive at the desired expression. I think that from now, when I post here I will make sure I write what I have so far because me not understanding something could be due to a previous misconception.

Comment: @KanyeWest Writing what you have tried will be very helpful, and allow others to guide you (esp in sporting errors or misconceptions that you have). This is why people ask you to "show your work", especially for standard problems like this.